# Can we add Ada syntax highlight?

Tags: feature-request, syntax-highlighting

Ada syntax uses `'` notation for both character and attribute notation. Syntax highlighter tends to generalizing `'` as beginning of a character or a string and the second one as end notation.

#### lang-ada

```ada
with Ada.Text_IO; use Ada.Text_IO;

procedure Main is
   C : Character := '.';
   S : String := "String of characters";
   L : Integer := S'Length;
begin
   Put_Line("String contains " & L'Img & " character" & C);
end;
```

The colorized string have taken a chunk of the code that's not supposed to be a string. If there are more than one spaces between first `'` and second `'` then its not a character nor a string.

#### lang-vhdl

```vhdl
with Ada.Text_IO; use Ada.Text_IO;

procedure Main is
   C : Character := '.';
   S : String := "String of characters";
   L : Integer := S'Length;
begin
   Put_Line("String contains " & L'Img & " character" & C);
end;
```

The `lang-vhdl` identifier have better syntax highlight. So maybe the alternative could be to borrow the syntax highlight from `lang-vhdl`.

Comment: There is no `lang-ada` identifier. It's reverting to default and Prettify is attempting to highlight it based on whatever language it thinks it is.

Comment: What about `lang-vhdl`? is that supported? because it has kinda the same syntax.

Comment: Yes, there are `lang-vhd` and `lang-vhdl` identifiers. Try one and see if it highlights properly.

Comment: Yeah it does. So while `lang-ada` syntax is not supported is it good idea to use `lang-vhdl` as identifier for Ada language instead?

Comment: Note the related question at http://stackoverflow.com/questions/20125474/google-prettify-ada-syntax

Comment: Now both versions look the same and seem good. But this compares poorly with what I have got in https://stackoverflow.com/a/66770211/1092849 Are different versions used here in meta and in the main site?

Comment: It seems that the ada highlight is actually not working on Stackoverflow nor here, but it is supported by highlight.js Why? Could it be enabled? https://github.com/highlightjs/highlight.js/blob/main/SUPPORTED_LANGUAGES.md